# Passing NSArray between 3 functions-retain or copy?

Tags: objective-c

`Class A` is passing `NSArray` to a function in `classB`, which in turn-pass it to `classC` , than classC use it for a while .

I know that if classB retains the NSArray with autorelease, than classC can use it safely because autorelease holds for 1 passing. is that right ?

Or , should i do something like that :

```
classB

NSArray *local=[argumentArrayFromA copy]; //should i autorelease it ??
[classC send:local];

classC
NSArray *goal=[argumentArrayFromB copy];
//use "goal" here safely .
```

Comment: Is ARC not an option? It simplifies memory management and allows your code to focus more on what it needs to do and not so much about dealing with memory.

Comment: Thats true but the code is really big now and not having ARC so we are continue without it for now. i guess the answer to my question is quite easy anyway .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're passing an array around and not modifying it anywhere, you don't want to copy it - that is just wasting memory. Stick with retain.

Comment: retain and autorelease is safe ?

Comment: Yep, with retain you're just claiming the object. So long as you balance that with a release when you're done with it (at the end of the method that uses it) everything balances out.

Comment: I asked about autorelease, that i know it only holds it to the next function that gets it, and thats it, so if A autorelease it only B can use it and not C. is it right ?

Comment: autorelease is a little more complicated than that. It means "release this object sometime in the future" which means that it should be released sometime in the future outside the current scope (which could be a method, a loop, or an explicit autorelease scope). Some of the most difficult to track down bugs I've encountered in programming came from someone (me or another developer) misusing autorelease. The best rule I've heard is to only use autorelease when you are returning an object from a function that you expect the caller to take ownership of (and thus call `-retain`)